# MongoDB: Filter using data from multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, schema, aggregation-framework

I have an application that stores users and their behavior in the form of events. There are two collections, one for the users and one for the events. The documents look like this:

**User**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593aa71e2f9d5140000bb44e"),
    "name" : "Antonette Ortiz",
    "country" : "France"
}
```

**Event**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593aaa84c685604066a6a0cf"),
    "name" : "message_sent",
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-11-01T04:39:52.667Z"),
    "user" : ObjectId("593aa728d135484002399bac"),
    "attributes" : {
        "str" : "plum",
        "int" : 82
    }
}
```

Now I want to be able to fetch a list of users not only by their attributes, but also in regard to the events they have triggered and with respect to a certain timeframe.

An example query would be something like: **"All users from France that have at least sent 3 messages within the last 7 days".**

How can I achieve this using MongoDB, also in regard to performance (if I have several million events for example)? Is this even possible with just the two collections, or do I have to use aggregation / map reduce? If so, what would you recommend how to change in the schema?

Comment: Either aggregation with lookup, or on application level.  mapreduce works with a single collection only, so it will require a temporary collection to do lookup, which is hardly suitable for operational queries.

Comment: Can you provide an example for the aggregation using lookup? And how would you approach this on the application level? Do you mean to request the data and then manually merge it?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/, feel free to ask, if you face any particular problems. With application layer - yes. Fetch all matched user ids from events (again with aggregation, but without lookup), then fetch users by ids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MongoDB documentation

> The $lookup stage does an equality match between a field from the
>   input documents with a field from the documents of the “joined”
>   collection.

For eg

**"All users from France that have at least sent 3 messages within the last 7 days".**

To retrieve data for above mentioned criteria its aggregate query will be as follows

```
db.Event.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {
            name:'message_sent',
            timestamp:{$gte:ISODate("2016-10-25T04:39:52.667+0000"),$lte:ISODate("2016-11-01T04:39:52.667+0000")}
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
               _id:{user:'$user'},
               counter:{$sum:1}
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $lookup: {
                "from" : "User",
                "localField" : "_id.user",
                "foreignField" : "_id",
                "as" : "user"
            }
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $match: {
             'user.country':'France' ,
            counter:{$gte:3}
            }
        },

    ]



);
```